# ng-repeat with inline text editing affects other items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular (`"angular": "~1.4.3"`), I have a ng-repeated list which I'd like to add items to and edit the item name inline using a text box.

[image]

The problems occur when I add more than one new item to the array. When I change the text in one, it affects the other. I typed `Hello` for line item 1, and it pushed `H` onto line item 2, and the rest on 1:

[image]

This is how I'm adding new objects (using `unshift` to force it to top of list):

```
   $scope.addObj = function () {
        $scope.new_categories.unshift({
            category : '',
            other data...
        });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in new_categories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchCategories track by $index" class="newly-added">
    <td class="third-width-input">
        <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="New Category" class="form-control" ng-blur="" ng-model="c.category">
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

**EDIT: Be advised**, using `$index` suggested in the answer will change the structure of your object.

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/6GLHXsvjbwRnfWueY4PH?p=preview)

Binding the model as I originally have, `c.category_name` maintains:

```
{
   //This is a Category Object
    category_name: 'some string',
    other data on the category obj
}
```

But using `c.category_name[$index]` changes it:

```
{
   //This is a Category Object
   category_name: Object { 0 : 'some string' },
   other data on the category obj
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in new_categories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchCategories track by $index" class="newly-added">
    <td class="third-width-input">
        <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="New Category" class="form-control" ng-blur="" ng-model="c.category[$index]">
    </td>
    <button ng-class="{ 'button-error' : !c.category[$index].length }" type="button" ng-click="saveAddedCategory( c ); c.saving = true; c.updated = false" class="buttons green inline" ng-disabled="!c.category[$index].length">
        Save
    </button>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.saveAddedCategory = function(category) {
        console.log('cat', category);
    };
```

Console.log produces:

[image]

Comment: please add the plunker or js fiddle?

Comment: What calls addObj?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same `ngModel` for all of your inputs. You should change it to:

```
<input type="text"
  ng-model="c.category[$index]"
  name="category"
  placeholder="New Category"
  class="form-control"
  ng-blur="">
```

So you can have this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in new_categories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchCategories track by $index"
  class="newly-added">
  <td class="third-width-input">
    <input type="text"
      ng-model="c.category[$index]"
      name="category"
      placeholder="New Category"
      class="form-control"
      ng-blur="">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I thought `ng-model` on an object property assumed a different index by default. Good to know

Comment: Please see above edit. I'm getting weird changes when trying to save the category object

Comment: I can't see any *weird* thing. It's the expected behavior. Your `ngModel` should be like this.. `category[0] = 'dddd'.. category[1] = 'aaa'` and so on..

Comment: But I'm pushing an entirely new category object into `$scope.new_categories array`, which is an array of new category objects. And am binding to the `category` (which is the cat name) property of each iterated object in `$scope.new_categories`. It needs to be an object as I have other meta data about the new category in the object.

Comment: The naming may be confusing. `category` property is the `category name` of the `category` object. See above edit

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo to demonstrate what you trying and what are you expecting? For sure it will help a lot.

Comment: developer, perhaps it should be `ng-model="c[$index].category_name"`?

Comment: If you want to get only the string, you can do something like `c.category[$index][$index]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120062/discussion-between-growler-and-developer033).